# Simulate data as a disk\files\folder in windows explorer

Tags: windows, winapi, disk, windows-explorer, drive

Is there an API or straight forward way to simulate any data as a windows explorer drive/file-hierarchy? I don't want to create actual files I want to have a view on my data as though it were.

E.g. if my real data was in a database but I want it to look like a drive/folder/files?

Comment: You can write a shell namespace extension

Comment: Maybe [FOR XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) could deliver this kind of structure from your database.

Comment: @Filburt: How is that even **remotely** related?

Comment: @IInspectable Turning database data into a tree-like navigable structure? The question does not read **display data IN windows explorer** but **AS A windows explorer**.

Comment: @Filburt: It reads: *"simulate any data as a windows explorer drive/file-hierarchy"*. A shell namespace extension is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [shell namespace extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or a virtual file system.

Shell namespace extension has many shortcomings but if you need files to be only exposed and copied, it can work.

Virtual file system or disk can be created only with help of third-party solutions such as our Callback File System or CallbackDisk. This approach fully emulates the local disk and the filesystem up to possibility to manipulate individual sectors (but this depends on the way used, i.e. whether you emulate the disk or the filesystem).

Comment: If virtual file systems can only be created with the help of third-party solutions, then how are those third-party solutions implemented? They surely aren't implemented using third-party solutions, that are created using third-party solutions, that are created using third-party solutions, ...

Comment: @iinspectable Of course there's a kernel-mode driver in the end, but writing own filesystem driver has a prohibitive cost for a person who doesn't know from where to start. And maintenance cost is even higher.